# setup/run spark (spark-shell) on yarn client mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to make spark-shell working with YARN, however when I try to run the code like below:

```
spark-shell \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode client \
  --driver-memory 1g \
  --executor-memory 1g \
  --executor-cores 1
```

The stacktrace I got is:

```
   17/02/07 01:52:41 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:95)
    at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
17/02/07 01:52:42 ERROR client.TransportClient: Failed to send RPC 7605279734171920371 to /172.17.0.2:35136: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source)
17/02/07 01:52:42 ERROR cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Sending RequestExecutors(0,0,Map()) to AM was unsuccessful
java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC 7605279734171920371 to /172.17.0.2:35136: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$3.operationComplete(TransportClient.java:249)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$3.operationComplete(TransportClient.java:233)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:514)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:488)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.access$000(DefaultPromise.java:34)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise$1.run(DefaultPromise.java:438)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:408)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:455)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source)
17/02/07 01:52:42 ERROR util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread main
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.requestTotalExecutors(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend.stop(YarnSchedulerBackend.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.stop(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.stop(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:467)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$8.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1826)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1283)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1825)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:587)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:95)
    at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC 7605279734171920371 to /172.17.0.2:35136: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$3.operationComplete(TransportClient.java:249)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$3.operationComplete(TransportClient.java:233)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:514)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:488)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.access$000(DefaultPromise.java:34)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise$1.run(DefaultPromise.java:438)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:408)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:455)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source)
17/02/07 01:52:42 WARN metrics.MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:85)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:62)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:156)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
  at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:95)
  ... 47 elided
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
              ^
```

To me this looks more like YARN does not have spark libraries in it's context when running in client mode. I tried to add the `$SPARK_HOME/jars` into the yarn-site.xml file within the `yarn.application.classpath` configuration, but this seems not working either.

How this could work with spark-shell and yarn? I was trying to find an official instructions in terms of handling such issue, but no guidance about this is found.

Comment: Did you mean `--master yarn --deploy-mode client`?

Comment: yes I tried this too and no luck, I will change the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually the reverse way as I described. Due to the connection failure caused by Yarn + Java 8 problem(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-4714). The sparkContext failed to be created.

the change should be add the following section in the yarn-site.xml file:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Did this resolve your problem? I have the exact same issue, but this change didn't help me.

Comment: This change does solve my problem but I am not quite sure about yours. Please follow the JIRA ticket above to see if any solution could help.

Comment: is it necessary to restart - yarn, or other service after changing yarn-site.xml ?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this as below: 
ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.

My cluster is spark 1.6.2 and hadoop 2.6. It gives same issue when I kick off
spark-shell --master yarn-client

Solution:

1. copy spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar from local to hdfs such as 
   hdfs://Master:9000/spark/spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar
2. in spark-defaults.conf add following parameter
   spark.yarn.jars    hdfs://Master:9000/spark/spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar

then the issue fixed.