# Spark Shell with Yarn - Error: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

As a follow-up of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458812/running-spark-on-yarn-on-single-node) question, I'm getting a new error when I try to use Spark 2.1.1 over Yarn (Hadoop 2.8.0) on my single node machine. If I launch the Spark Shell with

```
spark-shell
```

it starts without problems. After having started Hadoop with the usual `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh`, if I use

```
spark-shell --master yarn
```

I get the following error:

```
17/06/10 12:00:07 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/06/10 12:00:12 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2320)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:96)
    at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:743)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
17/06/10 12:00:12 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
17/06/10 12:00:12 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
```

I'm new to Spark/Yarn, so I don't really know where to look for solutions. I tried what has been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42080446/setup-run-spark-spark-shell-on-yarn-client-mode) (which looks like a similar problem, since I'm using Java 8), but it didn't have any effect. I also tried using Java 7 (setting the `JAVA_HOME` variable to the JDK 7 installation folder), but I still got the same error. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `spark-shell` doesn't need argument `--master yarn`  if you have set `$HADOOP_HOME` and `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` are set.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I thought that `spark−shell` without arguments is meant to make Spark work in "standalone" mode. Are you saying that setting those variables is equal to give the argument `−−master yarn`? Should I set them in `spark−env.sh`?

Comment: if you don't define those variables then its standalone mode but if you define then its yarn mode. You should define it as environment variable i.e. if you are using linux then its in .bashrc file . Thats what the answer in your other question suggests.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan So when `--master yarn` should be used then?

Comment: its used with spark-submit command

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Sorry if I insist, but [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html) it gives an example with `spark−shell` and `−−master yarn`. What is that for? Thanks for the patience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146319/discussion-between-ramesh-maharjan-and-alessandro).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50388919/spark-2-3-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-io-netty-buffer-pooledbytebufallocator-me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem by using more or less the same method described by the answer by Liming Cen to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42080446/setup-run-spark-spark-shell-on-yarn-client-mode).

The only difference was that I added to my HDFS *all* the JARs contained in `$SPARK_HOME/libexec/jars`, compressed in a zip file.

In `$SPARK_HOME/libexec/conf/spark-defaults.conf` I then added the following line:

`spark.yarn.archive=hdfs:///user/MY_USERNAME/spark-archive.zip`

Answer (score 1):

There is chance that this is due to fact that java 1.8 is not installed/configured properly for all YARN nodes ... In case that you are using  Cloudera you have to ensure that property "Java Home Directory" is configured properly for all host inside "Configuration" tab of specific HOST . (eg. /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_144)

Answer (score 0):

For me , some of the HDFS libraries were missing on YARN Nodemanager node,
So after installing hadoop-hdfs  and hadoop-client package on YARN NodeManager VM ,issue got resolved

```
yum -y install hadoop-client.x86_64 hadoop-hdfs.x86_64
```

Answer (score -1):

You can surely run spark-shell on yarn with --master-yarn. However, to run spark-shell you have to use 'deploy-mode client' since the driver is going to run on the client in case of spark shell. Try this and post if you get some error

```
./bin/spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client
```