# Spark 2.3 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.metric

Tags: apache-spark

SPARK 2.3 is throwing following exception.  Can anyone please help!!  I tried adding the JARs

308  [Driver] ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster  - User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.metric()Lio/netty/buffer/PooledByteBufAllocatorMetric;
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.metric()Lio/netty/buffer/PooledByteBufAllocatorMetric;
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.NettyMemoryMetrics.registerMetrics(NettyMemoryMetrics.java:80)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.NettyMemoryMetrics.(NettyMemoryMetrics.java:76)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.(TransportClientFactory.java:109)
        at org.apache.spark.network.TransportContext.createClientFactory(TransportContext.java:99)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.(NettyRpcEnv.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnvFactory.create(NettyRpcEnv.scala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:249)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:175)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:423)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at com.voicebase.etl.HBasePhoenixPerformance2.main(HBasePhoenixPerformance2.java:55)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:706)
    315  [main] ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster  - Uncaught exception: 
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:486)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:345)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$5.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:800)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:259)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:824)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Boxed Error

Comment: Added <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.17.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.9.Final</version>
      </dependency>

Comment: NOT SURE WHAT IS CAUSING THIS ERROR ADDED PROPER JAR NO EFFECT.  ANY HELP??

Comment: I have the same here, any solution. Incredible Spark dependency hell!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark 2.3.0 netty version issue: NoSuchMethod io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.metric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137397/spark-2-3-0-netty-version-issue-nosuchmethod-io-netty-buffer-pooledbytebufalloc)

Comment: @Alchemist are you able to solve the issue because i am also facing the same.

Comment: excluding netty-all & netty from spark dependency and adding it directly worked for me. I used the version netty-all - 4.1.17.Final netty -  3.9.9.Final It looks like a conflict in jars

Answer (score 13):

This is because Hadoop binaries compiled with an older version and need us to just replace them. I haven't faced any issues with Hadoop by replacing them.

You need to replace `netty-3.6.2.Final.jar` and `netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar` from path `$HADOOP_HOME\share\hadoop` with `netty-all-4.1.17.Final.jar` and `netty-3.9.9.Final.jar`.

Comment: really. I took those jars from spark installation and repleced those in hadoop and it worked..

Comment: Yes it worked. Strangely the [docs](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/PooledByteBufAllocator.html) show that it is part of 4.0 but seems like it only got included after 4.1.

Answer (score 2):

This issue plagues due to mismatch of the version that Hadoop and Spark are compiled on for Netty. So you can follow this.

[Similar Issue , solved by manually compiling the Spark by using specific version of Netty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137397/spark-2-3-0-netty-version-issue-nosuchmethod-io-netty-buffer-pooledbytebufalloc)

And the other one as recommended by Suhas , by copying the content of SPARK_HOME/jars folder to the various lib folder or only the one in yarn inside HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop solves the problem also. But it's a dirty fix. So maybe use latest version of both or manually compile them.

Answer (score 2):

An older version of Netty was required by the aws-java-sdk. Deleting all the netty jars and removing the aws-java-sdk from the project solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Issue has been resolved by adding the below netty jars in the dependencies,

```
   "io.netty" % "netty-all" % "4.1.68.Final"
   "io.netty" % "netty-buffer" % "4.1.68.Final"
```

And excluding all existing netty jars by adding excludeAll code.

```
 val excludeNettyBufferBinding = ExclusionRule(organization = "io.netty.buffer")
excludeAll(excludeNettyBufferBinding)
```

Comment: The dependency part fixed it for me. +1

Answer (score 0):

this is due to hadoop and spark unsupported versions, in order to solve it add netty as a dependency, try with different hit & trial versions. For mine it worked with this version -> 4.1.53.Final

add this

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.netty</groupId>
<artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
<version>4.1.53.Final</version>
</dependency>
```