# Apache Zeppelin Spark java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io/netty/buffer/PooledByteBufAllocator.metric()Lio/netty/buffer/PooledByteBufAllocatorMetric;

Tags: pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I am running a problem when I try to call pyspark in Apache Zeppelin, see below.

Apache Zeppelin Version 0.8.0 
Spark 2.3.0 (git revision a0d7949896) built for Hadoop 2.7.3
Python 3.6.4
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b14, mixed mode)

I added in zeppelin-env.sh.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/scala/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/spark/bin
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark
```

Zeppelin notebook

```
%pyspark
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io/netty/buffer/PooledByteBufAllocator.metric()Lio/netty/buffer/PooledByteBufAllocatorMetric;
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.NettyMemoryMetrics.registerMetrics(NettyMemoryMetrics.java:80)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.NettyMemoryMetrics.<init>(NettyMemoryMetrics.java:76)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.<init>(TransportClientFactory.java:109)
    at org.apache.spark.network.TransportContext.createClientFactory(TransportContext.java:99)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.<init>(NettyRpcEnv.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnvFactory.create(NettyRpcEnv.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:423)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:930)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:921)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:921)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.spark2CreateContext(BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.scala:202)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.createSparkContext(BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.scala:124)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkScala211Interpreter.open(SparkScala211Interpreter.scala:87)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.NewSparkInterpreter.open(NewSparkInterpreter.java:102)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:62)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter.getSparkInterpreter(PySparkInterpreter.java:664)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter.createGatewayServerAndStartScript(PySparkInterpreter.java:260)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter.open(PySparkInterpreter.java:194)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:617)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:522)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:191)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
```

Comment: Can you switch Java from OpenJDK to Hava 8? https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: See if it is the same issue as - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50388919/spark-2-3-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-io-netty-buffer-pooledbytebufallocator-me